# Slack Event Subscription

Tags: c#, wcf, slack-api, slack

I'm currently trying to create some very bespoke functionality for my software team and thought of a great solution using the slack event subscriptions. The problem is, I am having problems getting the event information that I am after...So far I have managed to configure slack to call my WCF service, however, the 'event' parameter that includes the information that I am after is always null.

Here is what I have so far:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISlackTrelloService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "SlackPost", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string SlackPost(string type, string token, string challenge, string team_id, SlackEvent slackEvent);
}
```

The concrete implementation:

```
 public class SlackTrelloService : ISlackTrelloService
{
    public string SlackPost(string type, string token, string challenge, string team_id, SlackEvent slackEvent)
    {
        return challenge;
    }
}
```

The SlackEvent class:

```
[JsonObject(Id = "event", Description = "event", Title = "event")]
public class SlackEvent
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "event_ts")]
    public string EventTimestamp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "user")]
    public string User { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ts")]
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "item")]
    public string Item { get; set; }
}
```

Now, the SlackEvent object is the problematic bit of code because I want it to contain the information sent by Slack according to [this](https://api.slack.com/events-api) documentation. The other parameters all get populated correctly, just not the slackEvent object :(

At first I thought it was because the parameter name didn't exactly match, but even using @event (since event is a keyword in C#) didn't seem to work. I'm not sure if I am using the Newtonsoft JSON library incorrectly, or if there is something else that I am missing.

EDIT:
New method to capture the data in correct format

```
string SlackPost(string token, string team_id, string api_app_id, SlackEvent slackEvent, string type, string[] authed_users, string event_id, string event_time);
```

SlackEvent structure:

```
[JsonObject("event")]
public class Event
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "channel")]
    public string Channel { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "user")]
    public string User { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ts")]
    public string TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @spuriousGreek can you please tell me how did you wrote the action method against the Request Url to return challenge parameter? I'm kind of stuck at it. I'm using ASP.Net Core Mvc

Answer (score 0):

By C# is a bit rusty, but from what I can understand it looks as if your `SlackTrelloService` class implementation is incomplete.

Slack sends two different requests for events: a verification handshake and the actual event. Your class seams to aim to cover both types in one class, what I think will not work the way its currently implemented.

The verification handshake is only used once during event subscription and does NOT contain any event information. It looks like this: (from the official documentation)

```
{
    "token": "Jhj5dZrVaK7ZwHHjRyZWjbDl",
    "challenge": "3eZbrw1aBm2rZgRNFdxV2595E9CY3gmdALWMmHkvFXO7tYXAYM8P",
    "type": "url_verification"
}
```

You app need to reply correctly to the verification handshake to enable a successful event subscription.

The actual events send later look like this: (again from the official documentation)

```
 {
        "token": "z26uFbvR1xHJEdHE1OQiO6t8",
        "team_id": "T061EG9RZ",
        "api_app_id": "A0FFV41KK",
        "event": {
                "type": "reaction_added",
                "user": "U061F1EUR",
                "item": {
                        "type": "message",
                        "channel": "C061EG9SL",
                        "ts": "1464196127.000002"
                },
                "reaction": "slightly_smiling_face"
        },
        "event_ts": "1465244570.336841",
        "type": "event_callback",
        "authed_users": [
                "U061F7AUR"
        ]
}
```

As you can see it does not have the `challenge` property, but instead many others.

You also seam to only return the `challenge` in your class, but not the actual event info.

So here are my suggestions:

1. Make sure you have successfully subscribed to events within your Slack app. If not all you currently get is the verification handshake which does not include the event.
2. Make separate implementations to deal with the verification handshake and the event requests

Comment: My class is very incomplete and I thought exactly that (I need another method to accept the method information)...however, I cannot find any information on how to actually trigger the event request i.e. how do I tell Slack to call a separate method?
The method that is being called now is working because there was a configuration option in Slack that allowed me to specify a specific URL for the verficiation.

Comment: ok, cool. I think we are on the right track. Slack will send both request types to the same url, the one you specified in the config window. You will receive event request once the verification handshake has been completed (which you will see in the config window) and an event you subscribed to has happened. I recommend subscribing to [message](https://api.slack.com/events/message) and then just posing sth in a channel to trigger it.

Comment: I've edited the original post to reflect the changes that I made to capture the event data that is being fired over. I am now receiving all of the data correctly, except for the event information (the bit that I'm actually after!). I'm using the Newtonsoft JSON library to try to capture the event object, but perhaps I am misunderstanding something because the slackEvent is always null. It might be that I have to map to the exact "event" but since it's a keyword I tried to set the id of the data structure that I created i.e. [JsonObject("event")]